How to work together with NDSolveValue, FindRoot and NIntegrate?
I am trying to perform numerical integration using the following code:
lagrangian = 
  1/(6 \[Pi]) Sec[r]^3 Sqrt[4/(1 + Cos[r]^2 + Cos[r]^4) + (x1'[r])^2];

Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

eqofmotion = 
 Last[EulerEquations[lagrangian, x1[r], r][[1]] // 
     Numerator] /. {x1'[r] -> 1/y'[x], x1''[r] -> -y''[x]/y'[x]^3} /. 
  r -> y[x]

eq = eqofmotion y'[x]^3 // Simplify

R[rc_] := 
 NDSolveValue[{eq == 0, y[0] == rc, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, -8, 8}]

Rp[rc_] := D[R[rc][x], x]

xp[rc_] := 1/Rp[rc]

rc[lq_] := 
 rc1 /. Quiet@
   FindRoot[R[rc1][lq/2] == Pi/2 - 10^-3, {rc1, .0001}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 3, Evaluated -> False]

rc[1]

En[lq_?NumericQ] := -2 NIntegrate[(
   Sec[\[Chi]]^3 Sqrt[
    4/(1 + Cos[\[Chi]]^2 + Cos[\[Chi]]^4) + (xp[\[Chi]])^2])/(
   6 \[Pi]), {\[Chi], \[Pi]/2, rc[lq]}]

If I want to get the output of, say, En[1], I get errors. How to resolve this issue? Am I missing something here?

You should really test each step on its own before adding more steps that uses the last step. This way you know where the problem is.  I just did R[1] which is your first very call to NDSolve and got an error NDSolveValue::ndsz: At x == 0.46930048260328944`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

@Nasser I have just modified this answer for my specific problem of finding the integration. I thought it was just a warning message and, hence, ignored it.

It is not clear what do you try to solve?

@AlexTrounev Basically, I am trying to reproduce Figure 2 of this paper, for which I need to solve their integral number 9 and 10.

@codebpr Could you post the figure you computed?

@AlexTrounev Unfortunately, my figure doesn't match theirs. I think there is still some correction that needs to be done.

I tried a different approach, as given in this answer by Alex, and now the integral evaluates fine.
lagrangian = 
 1/(6 \[Pi]) Sec[r]^3 Sqrt[4/(1 + Cos[r]^2 + Cos[r]^4) + (x1'[r])^2]

Needs["VariationalMethods`"]

eqofmotion = 
 Last[EulerEquations[lagrangian, x1[r], r][[1]] // 
     Numerator] /. {x1'[r] -> 1/y'[x], x1''[r] -> -y''[x]/y'[x]^3} /. 
  r -> y[x]

eq = eqofmotion y'[x]^3 // Simplify

lag = lagrangian /. {x1'[r] -> 1/y'[x], x1''[r] -> -y''[x]/y'[x]^3} /. 
  r -> y[x]

ClearAll[R1, R1p, lag, lq, rc]

R1[rc_, lq_] := 
 NDSolveValue[{eq == 0, y[0] == rc, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, -lq/2, lq/2}]

R1p[rc_, lq_] := D[R1[rc, lq][x], x]

rc[x1_] := 
 rc1 /. Quiet@
   FindRoot[R1[rc1, x1][x1/2] == Pi/2 - 10^-3, {rc1, .0001}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 3, Evaluated -> False]

ClearAll[integral]

integral[lq_] := 
 lag /. y[x] -> R1[rc[lq], lq][x] /. y'[x] -> R1p[rc[lq], lq]

En[lq_] := -2 NIntegrate[integral[lq], {x, -lq/2, lq/2}]


I don't understand what they have shown in figure 2, since both integrals $E, E_0$ diverge.

@AlexTrounev maybe they have used a trick like taking a very small value like $\epsilon$ added in the expressions or something similar.
